# Angular 5 Selenium getallangulartestabilities

Tags: javascript, angular, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, xunit

I work on a solution with the following technologies: .net acceptance tests written using x.unit and selenium.

We have a frontend using angular 5. We use selenium and chrome driver to pilot the browser.

At some points in the code, we wait for the browser to be stable (e.g. after an action, e.g. a button clicked, we redirect to an url and we wait for the browser to be stable before doing an assertion). To achieve that, we use the following code:

```
public static void WaitTillStable(this IWebDriver driver)
       {
           try
           {
               var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Config.WaitTimeout);
               wait.Until(d =>
               {
                   try
                   {
                       var stable =
                           ((IJavaScriptExecutor)d).ExecuteScript("return window.getAllAngularTestabilities()[0].isStable()");

                       return stable != null && (bool)stable;
                   }
                   catch (Exception e)
                   {
                       return false;
                   }
               });
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(e);
           }
       }
```

I've several problems/questions:

1. I am not familiar at all with the function return window.getAllAngularTestabilities()[0].isStable(). I'm looking for some documentation/refrences that would explain it
2. the config.WaitTimeout, even when configured to 5 seconds, is overriden by the method window.getAllAngular ... and I have a timeout after 60 seconds.
   Is it possible to force a timeout or maximum amount of time for this method to be executed?
3. I am not sure when it is really needed to use that method. Most of the tests are using it, and even when I receive a timeout my tests succeed. So I don't really know if it's needed, or why it's needed. On top of that it's slowing down tests, most of the time for no reasons (or no reasons I could see/understand).

Best Regards,
Nicolas